# About Cloud Run charges by hardware resources: Am I billed for underused memory?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I have a question about Cloud Run: If I setup my service with 4GB of RAM and 2 vCPUs, for example, differing from the standard 256MB and 1 vCPU, will I have to pay much more even if I never consume all the resources I have made available? For example again, let's say that I set --memory to 6GB and no request ever consumes more than 2GB, will I pay for 6GB of RAM or 2GB, considering that the peak of usage was 2GB?

I am asking because I want to be sure that my application will never die out of memory, since I think that the default 256MB of Cloud Run isn't enough for me, but I want to be sure of how Google charges and scales.

Comment: You pay for what you allocate. Allocate 6 GB - Pay for 6 GB.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quote from the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/run/pricing#billable-time):

> You are billed only for the CPU and memory allocated during billable time, rounded up to the nearest 100 milliseconds.

Meaning, if you allocated 4GB of memory on your Cloud Run service, you're still billed with 4GB whether it's underused or not.

On your case, since you want to make sure that requests don't run out of memory, then you can dedicate an instance resource to each request. With this, you just find out the cheapest memory setting that can run your requests and limit the [concurrency](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/about-concurrency#concurrency_values) setting to one.

Or, take advantage of concurrency (and allocate higher memory) because Cloud Run allows concurrent requests so you have control on how many requests can share resources before it starts a new instance, which can be a good thing as it helps drive down costs and minimize starting many instances (see [cold starts](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips/general#starting_services_quickly)). This can be a better option if you are confident that certain amount of requests can share an instance without running out of memory.

> When more container instances are processing requests, more CPU and memory will be used, resulting in higher costs. When new container instances need to be started, requests might take more time to be processed, decreasing the performances of your service.

Note that each approach have different advantages and drawbacks. You should take note of each before making a decision. Experimenting with the costs by using [GCP Calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator) can help (the calculator includes [Free Tier](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-tier-usage-limits) on the computation).